# Pandas Index from objects

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to be able to have column labels in a DataFrame which are instances of some generic object. So instead of a str object, a simple class that wraps str and provides some additional functionality:

```
class WrapStr(object):
    def __init__(self,str):
       self.str = str
    def __eq__(self,other):
       return self.str == other.str
    def __repr__(self):
       return self.str
```

The problem is that pd.Index does not call the **eq** method on the WrapStr instance but instead just checks if the two instances are the same.

```
first_ins = WrapStr('col1')
my_ix = pd.Index([first_ins])
sec_ins = WrapStr('col1')

print first_ins in my_ix # True
print sec_ins in my_ix # False
```

It looks like the **contains** check is defined in https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/index.pyx lines 92 and 448.

Any ideas on how to support such extended column labels?

Comment: this is in general not possible. The strings need to be c-hashable, IOW, the c-libs that do index calcs are expecting strings. You can try defining ``__hash__``, might work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Jeff!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `__hash__` method to `WrapStr`:

```
class WrapStr(object):
    def __init__(self,str):
       self.str = str
    def __eq__(self,other):
       return self.str == other.str
    def __repr__(self):
       return self.str
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.str)

first_ins = WrapStr('col1')
my_ix = pd.Index([first_ins])
sec_ins = WrapStr('col1')

print first_ins in my_ix # True
print sec_ins in my_ix # False
```

Comment: Excellent. That works and makes pandas even more useful for me. Thank you.